# Solr 'Invalid Date String' Exception when hh:mm:ss = 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, date, time, solr, dataimporthandler

I am using DataImport with Solr to import records from a mySQL database.  The query to extract the records, as defined in data-config.xml, is as follows:

```
SELECT reference_id, first_name, last_name, DATE_FORMAT(open_date_et, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') AS open_date_et
FROM   srv_req_table
```

`open_date_et` is defined as type `date` in the schema configuration.

This has been working fine for me for quite a while.  Today, I got a

```
Solr 'Invalid Date String' Exception
```

on one of the records it attempted to import.  The date in question was "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z".  This problem only seems to occur if the date is the first day of the year, and the time is "00:00:00". When I added a second and changed it to "00:00:01", it worked.  Is this a known issue or am I missing something?

Comment: So you're experiencing an error in Solr, not in MySQL, correct?

Comment: Correct.  The error is in Solr when running DataImport.  The SQL query I listed above is what is defined in the data-config.xml Solr configuration file - to show that I have the date formatted correctly.

Comment: Did you ever get any resolution on this? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: No resolution.  I let it go as I've not encountered that data condition again, but my guess is that it's a bug and should probably be reported to the SOLR team.